# C++ name collisions with typedef alias and inherited names

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces, typedef

I have a problem with name collisions. I am editing massively typedefed wrapped system and I want to avoid following name collision:

```
namespace NS{
  struct Interface{};
}
struct OldInterface: private NS::Interface{};
typedef OldInterface Interface;
struct Another : Interface{ // Derived correctly from OldInterface
  Another(Interface p){} // C2247 - in struct scope Interface means NS::Interface
};
```

I tried namespacing - but in objects it is implicitly cut.
I also tried private inheritance, which lead me to another error.

So question: Is it a way how to use it with above names? 
For example is a way how to force in-struct scope to use namespaced inherited names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explicitly state that you want the `Interface` from the global namespace:

```
struct Another : Interface{
  Another(::Interface p){}
  //      ^^
};
```

If you find yourself needing to qualify this a lot, you could introduce a local alias for the type:

```
struct Another : Interface{
  using Interface = ::Interface;
  //or typedef ::Interface Interface if you can't use C++11
  Another(Interface p){}
};
```